# Problem with constructor, destructor and =operator in linked list

Tags: c++, class, constructor, linked-list, destructor

So I have a problem where my code builds successfully but once I run it on Visual Studio,it stops with "Insufficient system resources exist to complete the requested service.". The code is basically creating a linked list and I am implementing a Set class that creates the list and conducts basic operations on it.

I believe it is a problem with my copy constructor, destructor and =operator. Below is the code:

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Set.h"

using namespace std;

int  main()
{
    Set a;
    a.insert("aa");
    a.insert("bb");
    a.insert("cc");
    a.insert("dd");

    Set b;
    b.insert("ee");
    b.insert("ff");

    Set c;
    Set c(b);
    cout << "C is " << endl;
    c.dump();
    cout << endl;
    c = a;
    cout << "C is " << endl;
    c.dump();
```

**Set.h**

```
class Set
{
public:
    Set();
    bool empty() const;
    int size() const;
    bool insert(const ItemType& value);
    bool erase(const ItemType& value);
    bool contains(const ItemType& value) const;
    bool get(int pos, ItemType& value) const;
    void swap(Set& other);
    void dump();

    ~Set();
    Set(const Set& other);
    Set& operator=(Set other);

private:
    struct Node
    {
        ItemType data;
        struct Node* next;
        struct Node* prev;

    }m_dummy;

    Node *m_dummyPtr;
    int m_size;

};
```

**Set.cpp** //copy constructor, destructor and =operator only

```
Set::~Set()
{
    Node* current = m_dummyPtr->next;
    Node* next;
    for (int i = 0; i < m_size;i++)
    {
        next = current->next;;
        delete current;
        current = next;
    }
    m_dummyPtr->next = nullptr;
    m_dummyPtr->prev = nullptr;

}

Set::Set(const Set& other)
{
    m_size = other.m_size;
    Node* p = other.m_dummyPtr->next;

    m_dummyPtr = &m_dummy;
    m_dummyPtr->data = {};
    m_dummyPtr->next = m_dummyPtr;
    m_dummyPtr->prev = m_dummyPtr;

    if (m_size == 0)
        ;
    else
    {
        for (int i = 0;i < m_size;i++)
        {
            insert(p->data);
            p = p->next;
        }
    }
}

Set& Set::operator=(Set other)
{
    if (this != &other) {
        swap(other);
    }
    return *this;
}
```

Set Insert function implementation

```
bool Set::insert(const ItemType& value)
{
    if (m_size == 0)
    {
        Node* newNode = new Node;
        newNode->data = value;
        newNode->prev = &m_dummy;
        newNode->next = &m_dummy;

        m_dummy.next = newNode;
        m_dummy.prev = newNode;

        m_size++;
        return true;
    }
    else if (contains(value))
    {
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        Node* newNode1 = new Node;
        Node* p = m_dummy.prev;
        m_dummy.prev = newNode1;
        newNode1->data = value;
        newNode1->next = &m_dummy;
        newNode1->prev = p;
        p->next = newNode1;
        m_size++;
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your error message sounds like you don't have any RAM left to run your program. Does your program run if you remove everything after `b.insert("ff");` from `main`?

Comment: yup, if I comment it out, it works

Comment: Probably somewhere you don't initialize `m_size` which results in you allocating huge amounts of memory. I'd put a watch on that variable in your debugger and see what values it takes up for each set.

Comment: Why do you believe it is a problem with your copy constructor, destructor and =operator?

Comment: because the code runs fine without those. I can execute the other functions

Comment: @AbilashSivalingam That is a reasonable, yet weak, conclusion. You should do some debugging to confirm your guess. Your first goal should be to determine where your program crashes -- what is the last line executed, and what are the values of variables at that point. Use that to build a [mre] if it doesn't immediately tell you what's wrong. (I cannot check their accuracy without a [mre], but heuristics suggest you might have an infinite loop in your copy constructor.)

Comment: (I should probably make sure you don't take offense from multiple links to [mre]. Please don't -- it's a shortcut. Typing `[mre]` in a comment produces that link, which means less typing.)

Comment: ok thansk for the help! I've been testing it out, and I believe there is a memory leak with the destructor actually, when it goes to 0 elements within the set. When I was testing the erase function, this problem was also occurring so I am inclined to believe that it is that

Comment: @AbilashSivalingam It just occurred to me that for what I suspect, the only missing piece is the implementation of `Set::insert()`, so adding that might be enough, rather than making sure every used function is implemented. *Of course, that would be if cleaning up the destructor does not resolve this problem.*

Comment: I added the set insert function. However, I still have no idea what I need to do with the destructor. Sorry, Im at a loss here.

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with your copy constructor. To see the problem, it helps to have documentation of your other functions. In particular:

```
/**
 * Inserts `value` into `*this`, but only if `*this` does not already contain `value`.
 * Side effect: if `value` is inserted, the size is updated.
 */
bool Set::insert(const ItemType& value)
```

That side effect is relevant! Look at what your copy constructor does. It first sets the size to the intended **final** size, then it proceeds to call `insert()` for each element to insert. Each such call increases the size *beyond the intended final size*. At best, you are looking at `m_size` being twice the number of nodes in the list (until the copy is copied, when size becomes at least triple what it should be, and so on).

However, the situation is worse than that. The loop controlling the insertions will run `m_size` times, and each iteration potentially increases `m_size`. Your setup is basically the following (I've inlined `insert()` and removed some code to focus on the problem):

```
for (int i = 0;i < m_size;i++)
    if (!contains(value))
        m_size++;
```

If, for some reason, your `contains()` function was to fail by always returning `false`, you are looking at an infinite loop, as both the loop control variable, `i`, and the ending condition, `m_size`, would be incremented with each iteration. A quick band-aid for this potential problem is to loop until `i < other.m_size`, as the other's size will not change. Even better would be to drop `i` and loop until `p == &other.m_dummy` (I don't know why you wasted space on `m_dummyPtr`). Still, that does not address the underlying issue.

---

When writing code, you should already have a good idea of what the code does; you should be able to explain in English (or your preferred human tongue) what the code is supposed to do. In this case, it looks like the intent is for the copy constructor to first initialize `*this` as an empty list, then copy elements from `other` to `*this`. So do that. C++11 gave us a tool called a [delegating constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list#Delegating_constructor) that lets this be done without code repetition, and that in this case might prevent the logical error.

```
Set::Set(const Set& other) : Set()  // Delegate to construct an empty list
{
    // Copy the nodes of `other` to `*this`.
    Node* p = other.m_dummyPtr->next;
    if (other.m_size == 0)
        ;
    else
    {
        for (int i = 0;i < other.m_size;i++)
        {
            insert(p->data);
            p = p->next;
        }
    }
}
```

I'll throw in another improvement for free. Don't write extra code to handle special cases that would have handled themselves. (This tip also applies to the `insert()` function.) One of the benefits of using a sentinel node (the `m_dummy` field) is that you often do not have to account for an empty list. Yet you have written extra code for that case. With a sentinel node, if your main codepath cannot handle an empty list, you likely have a logical error. Here's your `insert()` function without the check for being empty.

```
Set::Set(const Set& other) : Set()
{
    // Copy the nodes of `other` to `*this`.
    Node* p = other.m_dummyPtr->next;
    for (int i = 0;i < other.m_size;i++)
    {
        insert(p->data);
        p = p->next;
    }
}
```

This will still work because the body of the loop is not executed when `other.m_size == 0`, so there is no need to add an extra check for that condition. Also, we can further trim things by getting rid of `i`:

```
Set::Set(const Set& other) : Set()
{
    // Copy the nodes of `other` to `*this`.
    for (Node* p = other.m_dummy.next; p != &other.m_dummy; p = p->next)
        insert(p->data);
}
```

That's quite a bit less code to write and maintain than you currently have. Fewer places for bugs to creep in.